# What does svsec in \@svsec stand for?

Tags: latex-base, tex-history

Most of the following text you could probably skip. I just put it down there to show my effort.

## What does it do? Pretty sure I understand this already...

In the LaTeX kernel, the generic heading code `\@startsection` eventually decides whether or not to typeset a number (aside from the asterisk character choice).
A choice is made by comparing the value of the register/counter `\c@secnumdepth` to the value of the second parameter (`#2`). A number box is typeset if `#2` is greater than the `\c@secnumdepth` (default 2).

**`\@svsec` is the box that holds the formatted register value. I would expect it to have been named `\@secnumbox` or something more semantically associated to its purpose.**

- Why is this not the case?
- What is/was the logic behind the name?

The thing either becomes

```
\let\@svsec\@empty % hide number
```

or

```
\protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax} % show number
```

Comment: "SaVe SECtion"??  Maybe because if you are deeper than the seccnum-depth, it doesn't save it.  A pure SWAG disclaimer applies.

Comment: I always assumed the `v` was for value and the `sec` was for section and the `@` was for luck which just leaves the first `s` about which I haven't a clue. You could ask Leslie but I doubt he'll remember after all this time:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Haha. +1 `@` for luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being and to get this question closed up, I'm gonna go with

> Lucky Save Value Section

Leslie, please forgive me if I'm wrong.